# Drupal 9 paragraph translated content reverted back to english when updating the content langugage and translation?

Tags: drupal, content-management-system

I have been using content translation and Content Moderation modules on my site. We had wrongly checked the entity reference revision field (**** unsupported***) in the content language and
translation.

We had an issue when adding a new paragraph component to the Default Language's existing content. A new paragraph was added to the existing content but not displayed in another language.

Then we unchecked the entity reference revision field in content language and translation and then the new paragraph component which added to the existing content was displayed in the other language.

We already added the translation for other languages but translated content in other languages was reverted back to the default language.

Why did it revert back to the Default language for translated content?

How could I resolve this issue? Please guide me.